# PHP how to use preg_match() to extract substring starting with x and ending with y

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I am trying to use preg_match() to isolate a substring in a string (which consists of a page of HTML code) that starts with `amp-img>` and ends in `img>`

```
$result = preg_match('/' . preg_quote('img>') . '.*?' . preg_quote('amp-img>') . '/', $text);
```

What am I doing wrong here? I want $result to store the substring between `img` and `amp-img`

Comment: What is the real `$text` value? What are `x` and `y` (if they are literal values, there is no point preg_quoting them)?

Comment: I am writing a HTML to AMP-HTML converter, I will edit the ticket @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Ok. Just mind that `.` does not match linebreak symbols by default. You might need `/s` modifier. Also, if the text is Unicode, the `/u` modifier might also be necessary. Also, no symbol in `amp-img>` needs preg_quoting. [UPD] And you must be confusing a preg_match with a preg_replace. See the answer below. Right now, it is not clear to me what you are up to.

Comment: Besides, isn't a DOM parser the best tool for mark-up text like this?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Wiktor, I have attempted to update the question with the appropriate preg_match() syntax

Comment: What doesn't work? What do you get and what is the expected result? I guess you misanderstood what is returned by preg_match.

Comment: Toto is right. You might want to check this: `preg_match('/' . preg_quote('img>') . '.*?' . preg_quote('amp-img>') . '/', $text, $matches); print_r($matches);`

Comment: I think I did @toto I am hoping to store the substring in $result

Comment: The return value of preg_match is 1 if pattern match, 0 if it doesn't or false if an error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> Description
>
> int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
>
> Searches subject for a match to the regular expression given in pattern.

And you are providing `''` as the second argument, and not using the result.

Desirable call would look like:

```
preg_match('/'.preg_quote('amp-img>').'.*?'.preg_quote('img>') .'/', $text, $result);
```

Did you mean `preg_replace`?

Comment: Sorry @Bvengerov I have fixed that

Comment: @BarneyChambers Check how the result is got in the provided code. The function would return 0, 1 or false, and if you want the matches themselves, you should provide a variable to store them in as the third argument.

Comment: P.S. The regex looks fine.

Comment: @BarneyChambers show an example of the `$text` then.

Comment: Thank you BVengerov, this is actually the answer I needed

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Prepared Patterns](https://t-regx.com/docs/handling-user-input) for unsafe data in regexp:

```
<?php
$result = Pattern::inject('@.*?@', ['amp-img>', 'img>'])->match($text)->all();
```

The values will be injected into `@`, but safe.